# how to pass session variable to next page in PHP

Tags: php, session

I am setting username of a user as a session and then printing that at index page but is nothing displays..
my `login.php`

```
$user = $_POST["username"];
$_SESSION["username"]=$user;  // session started with username if I echoed this here it displaying correctly..
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

after login I'm redirecting the page to `index.php` and it is as below :

```
<?php session_start();
include("connection.php");
print_r($_SESSION); // print_r() displays nothing ???
?>
```

On executing above code this doesn't display's anything inside print_r() why? and how can I resolve this and how should I print session value now ?

Comment: in login.php may be you missed session_start()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session_start();` **also** on `login.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_POST["username"];
$_SESSION["username"]=$user;
header('Location: index.php');
exit();
```

---

**Note:**

While developing, use `display_errors` to track any `errors` or `warnings` your script may have, in this case `include("connection.php");`may have them and that's why  "***print_r() displays nothing ???***".
To enable error reporting on php code, append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script.